# Combining two matrices, preserving their element value

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix

I'm using `OpenCV` in `C++`. I have two single channel matrices, one with values of either `0 or 2`, the other with either with values `0 or 3` for each element. I want to combine the two to use as a mask in the `grabCut` function.

I would like to merge them such that my new combined matrix contains either 0, 2, or 3, where appropriate. I tried a bitwise OR operation, but it seems that this only gives me a matrix with values 0 or 255 exclusively where a 3 or 2 is.

```
combined = (greenMaskForGrabcut == 3) | (redMaskForGrabcut == 2);
```

How can I preserve the 3 or 2 values for each element? Thanks

Comment: I'd assume you want 0 if both matrix contain 0, want 2 if matrix-1 contains 2 and matrix-2 contains 0, want 3 if matrix-1 contains 0 and matrix-2 contains 3. But what would you like your combined matrix to contain when matrix-1 contains 2, and the other contains 3?

Comment: The 2 and 3 values will never overlap, as its taken from a user drawn mask, so the pixel can only be 2 or 3. So it should technically not be possible where both matrices contain a value other than 0.

Comment: Not sure that is appropriate syntax for C++? Xcode gives me an error "No viable conversion from 'cv::MatExpr' to 'bool'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV has a bitwise_or operation specifically for arrays:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html

`void bitwise_or(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, OutputArray dst, InputArray mask=noArray())`